# One of the history maker

Tags: riddle, rhyme, history

> I fall with my holey sleeves
>   
>   Release the load then I heave
>   
>   A five-year mission made me a crew of the war
>   
>   To boldly take action where no man has taken before
>   
>   When the dateline was almost torn up
>   
>   The fire of revenge I had lit up
>   
>   The successor came quite early
>   
>   Yet my body still varied
>   
>   It was not my intention to retain
>   
>   As the reputation was hard to obtain

**What am I ?**

*Hint 1:*

> The title was inspired from a Vietnam War movie quote, which made in 1991, based on a military novel that shared the same name. 
>  
>  Though the answer itself didn't starred in it, the quote may help you to identify the thing behind puzzle in some way.

*Hint 2:*

> What it does is **tactical**, not **strategic**, even though the results were crucial. 
>  
>  It may help you a lot to solve the puzzle if you put the first two hints together.
>  
>  (It's also fit to combine it with the first two line of the riddle!)

*Hint 3:*

> Two names people used to called it: one came from navy, the other came from army.

*Hint 4:*

> Its skill only came in handy through the 1940s, and it became old-fashioned after that era.

Comment: is the answer related to a famous movie series?

Comment: @WeShall well, I wish I could found one, but the answer doesn't featured in any movie series, as far as I know. Maybe that could help you to recognize _a bit_ about what the answer is.

Comment: USS enterprise ncc 1701, seems to fit a few clues.

Comment: Have a little edit on the riddle, make some clue more specific. Oh gosh, @WeShall, you've got a clue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ...

> the Douglas SBD Dauntless

I fall with my holey sleeves

> A dive bomber (I fall) with distinctive dive brakes on the trailing edges of the wings that look like perforations; see [this picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Dauntless_bomb_drop.jpg/300px-Dauntless_bomb_drop.jpg).

Release the load then I heave

> A bomber, so it released the bomb and then got itself out of there.

A five-year mission made me a crew of the war

> Saw its major service life from 1940 to 1944 during WWII.

To boldly take action where no man has taken before

> Served aboard the USS Enterprise CV-6 (hence the play on the tag line from Star Trek)
>  
>  *Addtional info from OP:*
>  
>  Here's another meaning that I had came up with, as this line was written:
>  
>  To be precise, SBDs went into service on [Yorktown-class aircraft carriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yorktown-class_aircraft_carrier), including USS Enterprise (CV-6) and [USS Yorktown (CV-5)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Yorktown_(CV-5)). It was the SBDs on USS Yorktown participated in [the Battle of the Coral Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Coral_Sea), the first battle that only aircraft carriers engaged on each other. 
>  
>  That also fit the line "take action where no man has taken before".

When the dateline was almost torn up

> not sure what is meant here; other answers have several good interpretations, one of which is surely on point
>  
>  *OP:*
>  
>  That's actually talking about the Battle of Midway, as the dateline is near from Midway Atoll.

The fire of revenge I had lit up

> During the Battle of Midway in early June 1942, four squadrons of Navy SBD dive bombers attacked and sank or fatally damaged all four Japanese fleet carriers present—three of them in the span of just six minutes (Akagi, Kaga, Sōryū and, later in the day, Hiryū).  This avenged the losses at Pearl Harbor.

The successor came quite early

> [The Curtiss SB2C Helldiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_SB2C_Helldiver) was a carrier-based dive bomber aircraft produced for the United States Navy during World War II. It replaced the Douglas SBD Dauntless in US Navy service. The SB2C was much faster than the SBD it replaced. First flight was 1940, and principle production from 1943-1945 -- practically on the heels of the SBD it was made to replace.

Yet my body still varied

> The SBD went through many updates in a short timespan.
>  - The original model first entered service in mid-1939, and came in two models, designated the **SBD-1** and **SBD-2** (the latter had increased fuel capacity and different armament).
>  - The next version was the **SBD-3**, which began manufacture in early 1941. It had increased armor, self-sealing fuel tanks, and four machine guns.
>  - The **SBD-4** doubled the voltage of the electrical system.  Some of these became **SBD-4P** reconnaissance aircraft.
>  - The next (and most produced) version, the **SBD-5**, had a more powerful engine and an increased ammunition supply.
>  - The final version, the **SBD-6**, had more improvements, but its production ended during the summer of 1944.

It was not my intention to retain

As the reputation was hard to obtain

> Aircraft design progression was fast and furious during WWII, so this model would quickly see an end to its usefulness. But it had earned its reputation: The SBD is best remembered as the bomber that delivered the fatal blows to the Japanese carriers at the Battle of Midway in June 1942.
>  
>  *OP:*
>  
>  These lines were actually talking about the evaluation between SB2Cs and SBDs: 
>  
>  Though SB2Cs are faster, and able to carry bombs up to 2,000 pounds (SBDs could only up to 1,200 pounds), **the control in low speed is so terrible** that pilots found it hard to land safely on an aircraft carrier, even to aim a target while diving. On the contrary, those easy-to-fly SBDs were even earned the nickname **"Slow But Deadly".** As for the SB2Cs, its codename became **"Son-of-a-Bitch 2nd Class".**

Hint 1:

> The title was inspired from a Vietnam War movie quote, which made in 1991, based on a military novel that shared the same name.  Though the answer itself didn't starred in it, the quote may help you to identify the thing behind puzzle in some way.
>  **The movie was *Flight of the Intruder* and did indeed get me looking into aircraft.**
>  
>  *OP:* **"Fighter pilots make movies, bomber pilots make... HISTORY!"**

Hint 2:

> What it does is tactical, not strategic, even though the results were crucial.
>  **The SBDs were used tactically, not strategically**

Hint 3:

> Two names people used to called it: one came from navy, the other came from army.
>  **The SBD ("Scout Bomber Douglas") was the United States Navy's main carrier-borne scout plane and dive bomber from mid-1940 through mid-1944.**
> **One land-based variant of the SBD — in omitting the arrestor hook — was purpose-built for the U.S. Army Air Forces, as the A-24 Banshee.**

Hint 4:

> Its skill only came in handy through the 1940s, and it became old-fashioned after that era.
>  **As already noted, it quickly became obsolete, and in any case its primary purpose was service in WWII**

Comment: You've got the right one! Line 5 and line 6 are actually talking about the same thing. If you don't mind, I would like to edit some further explanation from yours.

Comment: @ShaneHsu Be my guest.

Answer (score 3):

Although some don't seem to quite fit, there's some strong connections with

> The Enola Gay

I fall with my holey sleeves

> Fall from the sky

Release the load then I heave

> Release the bomb

On a five-year mission I did swear

> Manhattan project (4+ years)

Go boldly into the azure frontier

> Plane flies

When the dateline was almost torn up

> Negotiations for surrender with Japan had failed.

The fire of revenge I had lit up

> Retaliation for declaring war

The successor came quite early

> The second atomic weapon was deployed by the B-29 airplane named Bockscar 3 days later.

Yet my body still varied

> Not sure what a varied body is.

It was not my intention to retain 
As the reputation was hard to obtain

> The bomb was intended to be released, or the infamy was not expected or wanted.

Comment: That's a nice try I admit, but unfortunately not the right one.

Comment: @ShaneHsu, okay.

Comment: Kind of complete explanation... you've earned my upvote. I want to say sorry for the quick reply in minutes.

Answer (score 2):

```
Are you...
```

> **B-26 Flak Bait**

```
I fall with my holey sleeves
```

> This aircraft has a reputation of surviving 1000 bullet holes

Working through other clues !!

Comment: Oh my, I didn't know such a legend lived in the past! (taking notes) But that was not the answer, maybe a second try?

Comment: SpaceShipOne? but it has more of a holey nose than sleeves :)

Comment: Ha, ha! That's creative, I should take another note then. You can check the comment I had left for @rand al'thor, it may help with your previous comment above. As for holey sleeves, well, think again :D

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd and 4th lines of the riddle hint towards

> [Star Trek](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/g/generodden390834.html) and the USS Enterprise, which, as well as being the name of various starships in the Star Trek universe, has also been the name of [various real-life ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ships_of_the_United_States_Navy_named_Enterprise).

I think the answer is

> **the [USS Enterprise CV-6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(CV-6))**, a WWII aircraft carrier.

*I fall with my holey sleeves*

> Perhaps something to do with the numerous guns on board the ship?

*Release the load then I heave*

> I can't even parse this line, sorry.

*A five-year mission made me a crew of the war*

> It was roughly 5 years from when *Enterprise* was first commissioned to her participation in the war.

*To boldly take action where no man has taken before*

> As well as being a Star Trek reference, this also describes the real-life *Enterprise*, which did things no other ship had done during WWII.

*When the dateline was almost torn up*

> This is probably a reference to the [Battle of Midway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(CV-6)#The_Battle_of_Midway), which took place close to the International Date Line.

*The fire of revenge I had lit up*

> *Enterprise* took part in the destruction of many Japanese craft, a kind of 'revenge' for the Pearl Harbour attack.

*The successor came quite early*

*Yet my body still varied*

> [Another *Enterprise*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(CVN-65)) was commissioned only a year after the CV-6 was scrapped, but its shape ('body') was different from its namesake.

*It was not my intention to retain*

*As the reputation was hard to obtain*

> *Enterprise* had a reputation for having been sunk: on three separate occasions the Japanese declared that she had gone down, but always she showed up again. She was also the most decorated US ship in WWII - another tough act to follow!

Comment: if this is the answer, then, this is more trivia than a riddle

Comment: Excuse me, the 3rd and 4th lines were **not** meant to lead directly to the answer. We know the movie from that famous quote, which I intended to make you come up with; However, the spaceship was the point where I emphasized, since there were more than one ship **shared its name in history**.

Comment: @ShaneHsu Something to do with [one of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ships_of_the_United_States_Navy_named_Enterprise) then?

Comment: @randal'thor That's what I'm talking about :)

Comment: @ShaneHsu I would guess [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(CV-6)), as the most famous ship on that list. The "fire of revenge" perhaps referring to revenge for Pearl Harbour? Not sure about "holey sleeves" or the "dateline" though (unless that's a reference to the International Date Line ...)

Comment: Nice try, then the 3rd line might help you out.

Comment: @ShaneHsu OK, totally overhauled my answer now.

Comment: Oh my goodness, that's... not the answer, unfortunately. The website has told me to _move the discussion to chat_, so I think my chances to leave more clues here have run out. At least, I could provide the last clue here: think twice about the 3rd line, is the ship being _primary or secondary_ in the puzzle?

Comment: @ShaneHsu Maybe a member of the Enterprise's crew? Hint 2 made me think it might be a tactical officer or something, but Rear-Admiral Fletcher doesn't seem to be a particularly well-known figure. (Also, don't worry *too* much about moving the discussion to chat; it's more of a suggestion than an instruction.)

Comment: Well then, you are on the right track that I guide you to. I suggest to put @John 's answer into consideration, since he got something you have missed.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> Viking 1 probe

I fall with my holey sleeves

> A reference to probe's solar panels

Release the load then I heave

> The probe comprised of a lander and an orbiter. Load being the lander, presumably.

A five-year mission made me a crew of the war

To boldly take action where no man has taken before

> No one's been to Mars yet

When the dateline was almost torn up 
The fire of revenge I had lit up

> The probe came close to crashing on Mars towards the end of its mission.

The successor came quite early 
Yet my body still varied

> Viking 2 dates were pretty close too.

It was not my intention to retain 
As the reputation was hard to obtain

> Not sure about this one. Viking was no doubt a milestone in NASA's space exploration.

Comment: That is a creative answer, but not the right one. When it comes to the word "war" in line 3, a war machine may much more reasonable than a spacecraft.

Comment: A challenge. Will muse over it.

Comment: Then I would suggest that to check other user's answer. Good luck!